# Sagemaker with tensorflow 2 not saving model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I am working with Keras and I am trying to train a model using Sagemaker. I have the following issue:
When I train my model using TensorFlow 1.12 everything works fine:

```
estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='entrypoint-2.py',
                            base_job_name='mlearning-test',
                         role=role,
                         train_instance_count=1,
                         input_mode='Pipe',
                         train_instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge',
                         framework_version='1.12.0')
```

My model is trained and the model is saved in S3. Not problems.

However, if I changed the framework version to be 2.0.0

```
estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='entrypoint-2.py',
                                base_job_name='mlearning-test',
                             role=role,
                             train_instance_count=1,
                             input_mode='Pipe',
                             train_instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge',
                             framework_version='2.0.0')
```

I get the following error:

```
2020-02-12 13:54:36,601 sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training WARNING  No model artifact is saved under path /opt/ml/model. Your training job will not save any model files to S3.
For details of how to construct your training script see:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#adapting-your-local-tensorflow-script
```

The training job is marked as successful but there is nothing in the S3 bucket and indeed there was not training.

As an alternative, I tried putting the py_version='py3' but this keeps happening. is there a major difference that I am not aware of when using TF2 on sagemaker?

I don't think the entry point is needed since it works fine with version 1.12 but in case you are curious or can spot something here it is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sagemaker_tensorflow import PipeModeDataset
#from tensorflow.contrib.data import map_and_batch

INPUT_TENSOR_NAME = 'inputs_input'  
BATCH_SIZE = 64
NUM_CLASSES = 5
BUFFER_SIZE = 50
PREFETCH_SIZE = 1
LENGHT = 512
SEED = 26
EPOCHS = 1
WIDTH = 512

def keras_model_fn(hyperparameters):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(WIDTH, 'relu', input_shape=(None, WIDTH), name = 'inputs'),
        #tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, WIDTH), name=INPUT_TENSOR_NAME),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')
    ])

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

def serving_input_fn(hyperparameters):
    # Notice that the input placeholder has the same input shape as the Keras model input
    tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, WIDTH])

    # The inputs key INPUT_TENSOR_NAME matches the Keras InputLayer name
    inputs = {INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: tensor}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

def train_input_fn(training_dir, params):
    """Returns input function that would feed the model during training"""
    return _input_fn('train')

def eval_input_fn(training_dir, params):
    """Returns input function that would feed the model during evaluation"""
    return _input_fn('eval')

def _input_fn(channel):
    """Returns a Dataset for reading from a SageMaker PipeMode channel."""
    print("DATA "+channel)
    features={
        'question': tf.FixedLenFeature([WIDTH], tf.float32),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
    }

    def parse(record):
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, features)
        #print("-------->"+str(tf.cast(parsed['question'], tf.float32))
        return {
            INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: tf.cast(parsed['question'], tf.float32)
        }, parsed['label']

    ds = PipeModeDataset(channel)
    if EPOCHS > 1:
        ds = ds.repeat(EPOCHS)
    ds = ds.prefetch(PREFETCH_SIZE)
    #ds = ds.apply(map_and_batch(parse, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    #                            num_parallel_batches=BUFFER_SIZE))
    ds = ds.map(parse, num_parallel_calls=NUM_PARALLEL_BATCHES)
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    return ds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're correct, **there has been a major, beneficial change last year in the SageMaker TensorFlow experience named the *Script Mode* formalism**. As you can see in the [SDK Documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

*"Warning.
We have added a new format of your TensorFlow training script with TensorFlow version 1.11. This new way gives the user script more flexibility. This new format is called Script Mode, as opposed to Legacy Mode, which is what we support with TensorFlow 1.11 and older versions. In addition we are adding Python 3 support with Script Mode. The last supported version of Legacy Mode will be TensorFlow 1.12. Script Mode is available with TensorFlow version 1.11 and newer. Make sure you refer to the correct version of this README when you prepare your script. You can find the Legacy Mode README here."*

with TensorFlow 2, you need to follow that *Script Mode* formalism and save your model in the `opt/ml/model` path, otherwise nothing will be sent to S3. *Script Mode* is quite straightforward to implement and gives better flexibility and portability, and this spec is shared with SageMaker Sklearn container, SageMaker Pytorch container and SageMaker MXNet container so definitely worth adopting

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am following now this example https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/keras_script_mode_pipe_mode_horovod/source_dir/cifar10_keras_main.py